# understanding the meaning of scalar in the inner product definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, inner-products

The definition is given below:

> [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpbt.png)

but I am wondering:

1-In (2) why the author is not putting $\bar{\alpha}$ which means the conjugate of $\alpha$?

2- can the second and the third properties help us to say that the inner product is bilinear? if so how?

Comment: In (2) that is how physicists do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. He defines it that way, it doesn't really make a difference.
2. No, property 4 and 2 tells you it's not bilinear.

If it's bilinear then $\overline{a}<x, y>=\overline{a <y, x>}=\overline{<y, ax>}=<ax, y> = <x, ay> = a<x, y> $ so that $a = \bar{a}$ which is not necessarily true.

Comment: could you provide details of $(2)$ please?

Comment: @Emptymind done

Answer (score 1):

From the last three properties we can derive that
$$\begin{align} \langle \alpha x,y \rangle 
&= \overline{\langle y,\alpha x \rangle} \\
&= \overline{\alpha \langle y,x \rangle} \\
&= \overline{\alpha} \overline{\langle y,x \rangle} 
= \overline{\alpha} \langle x,y \rangle.
\end{align}$$
So, in general, we cannot say that $x\mapsto \langle x,y \rangle$ is a linear map, we say instead that is *conjugate linear*.

Also, observe that if the vector space is *real*, then $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a *bilinear* map, because its linear in each of the both entries.

Comment: For that reason it's called a sesquilinear form, that means a "one and a half" linear form.